# Nav bar button bigger than the nav bar height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Let's have a a picture :

[image: Nav bar]

Is there a way to have a Navbar button bigger than the navbar it self, like the "O" button ?
Or If not, what is the best hack if i want to trie to have this renderer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way it make custom viewcontroller which support this logic.

For example you can create custom viewcontroller with method setNavigationBarByType:(YourType)

Then use this viewcontroller as parent viewController

Comment: I would have made a category for viewcontroller which would allow create a this button

Answer (score 0):

1. Try with clipSubview = NO for UINavigationBar --> Its UIView property so it should work over UINavigationBar as well but I'm not sure about this
2. Instead of using UINavigationBar use custom controls like, 
   UIView as a containerView
   --Backround UIImageView
   --Back UIButton Custom style
   --Right UIButton Custom style

Display this containerView in your RootViewController where you require to put common controls of your application. and the middle part of screen will be populated as per button tap event or screen flow.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create UILabel configure and set as navigation bar title view.
Added this button as subview to navigation bar title view.